# Page doesn't load css file after directory change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Since last 3 hours i am trying to sort out this problem but couldn't, i tried using solutions posted on other such stackoverflow questions, but didn't work.

So here's what my problem is:

I have a website which has two phases, one is for visitors other is for admins. Now earlier i had both admin and non-admin php files within root directory and js and css files in their respective folders namely "css" and "js" within root directory of website.

But to make everything sorted, i pulled all the admin panel related php files to a folder named "adpanel" within root directory and their css and js stored in their respective folders inside folder "adpanel".

And from here onwards the chaos began, the css failed to show up, even in firebug it showed nothing under it's css tab, it was empty. I thought the problem might have been because of the way i entered the path in href, but even after trying other ways, it failed to load.

But everything works perfect in chrome. I tried to clear whole data of firefox, but that didn't help either.

Please help me out!!

I think the problem is browser related, as explained earlier css loads perfectly in other browser. And now i tried calling the css file from older css folder(the one inside root directory) and it worked. But i've cleared up whole firefox, should i try re-installing firefox?

Update: Have tried reinstalling firefox too. Nothing changes.

**Final Update:** Guys it was the firefox causing problem. As i said earlier i uninstalled firefox(but not completely) and then again i installed but the problem remained, then after searching a while i first uninstalled firefox then went into APPDATA folder and deleted Mozilla Firefox folder.

Then i reinstalled firefox and alas it started working as expected and css began to show it's effect on pages.

Now, Thank You each and everyone(ofcourse including stackoverflow) who took their precious time for sorting out my problem. And my apologies if anyhow i fell short in providing proper information. I'll improve myself in better explaining my queries. Thank You once again. Good Day :)

Comment: check your browser console for errors

Comment: Provide some details, directory structure, html code...

Comment: Can you shows path of CSS file? CSS include statement I am asking.

Comment: @Lal It's displaying this message:12:33:50.660 Expected ':' but found '='.  Declaration dropped.1 adpanel_login.php

Comment: When you try to access the CSS directly in your browser, what do you get?

Comment: Look at the Network tab inside the Developer Tools, you should be able to see if the css is loaded.

Comment: @HonzaHaering When i enter same path in address bar of browser. It shows the file content.

Comment: @SharpEdge In Network tab, it's showing just the adpanel_login.php and jquery-1.7.2.min.js. It doesn't show CSS file.

Comment: @KrishnaSaraswat  could you please post the code of `adpanel_login.php` too

Comment: @Lal Done. Question updated

Comment: Try `$(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ });` instead of `$(window).on('load', function(){ /* code here */ });`

Comment: @Lal As none of the answers worked. Which one should i accept, or is it mandatory to accept an answer?

Comment: No no..since none has helped you, dont accept any..if you have no accepted Answers it is of high probability that somebody will post a useful answer..i too will try..

Comment: Oh you got the solution..sry..didnt notice that..so i think you should delete the question as the solution is not at all related to programming..

Comment: @Lal Unable to delete questions, as it has answers. So i myself have answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the firefox causing problem. I first uninstalled firefox then went into APPDATA folder and deleted Mozilla Firefox folder. Then i reinstalled firefox and it started working as expected and css began to show it's effect on pages.

Answer (score 0):

If your css is in root folder, I think you should just add `/` in the beginning of your CSS links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/masters.css" />
```

(sorry if I misunderstood your question)

Comment: Actually the css file was stored like this `root\css\masters.css` earlier but then when i moved it into new directory structure of which was like this `root\adpanel\css\` and after this it stopped showing up in firefox, though everything worked well in chrome and IE. 

And yes i tried even mentioning path like this too. But this didn't work either. Thanks for helping though :) Sorry if i couldn't make myself clear enough while questioning.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the `text/css` in your links, what you need is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/masters.css" type="text/css" />
```

And this SHOULD work.

***Note***
Please make sure that you are declaring these in the header and that there are no other style sheets after as they will be overwritten by them or classes/ids overwritten at least

Comment: There are no CSS files other than these two. And is it necessary for us to put type like, is it recommended cause i never do that, i just add the rel="stylesheet" and href.

And actually i uninstalled firefox, so right now i am downloading it again, so it might take sometime. But i'll let you know when it gets downloaded. And will try this. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: It is best to declare it as `text/css` as otherwise the browser may interpret it as JavaScript or any other file type, which none of us want! xD

Comment: True dat! :D @sam swift

Comment: I hope that I have helped you here :)

Comment: Ofcourse and thank you very much, but I don't know what to do as you know the actual problem was something else and none of the answer really helped sort that out. So I just wanted to ask that is it mandatory to accept an answer. If yes, wouldn't that be false advertising?

Comment: It would be misleading to some users, I wouldn't mark as correct, rather put an answer of your own with what fixed it that you can mark as correct after (I think) two days, this would be my solution here :)

Comment: Okay I'll do that. Thanks for your help. Once again :)